# Single pattern to accommodate multiple regular expression patterns using Java

Tags: java, regex

There's a requirement where in, I'm asked to come up with a logic to delete a specific set of log files with possible set of patterns and I'm able to create them individually but I'm finding it difficult to create one complete pattern that accommodate all these scenarios.

Considering "application" as the log file name that gets created, these are the scenarios that I'm supposed to handle:

1. "application.xml"
2. "application#number.xml"
3. "application.xml.2016-01-10"

Running these individual patterns, I'm able to delete the files that are intended to but I'm looking for a better version than having 3 individual patterns to do so. Any help or inputs on the same are much appreciated!

Code snippet:

```
public class PatternMatchPOC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File logsDirectoryPath = new File("C:\\POCLogs");
        FileFilter patternFilter = getFilter();
        File[] list = logsDirectoryPath.listFiles(patternFilter);
        if (list.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("File" + i + " : " + list[i].getName());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: No files available matching the pattern");
        }
    }

    public static FileFilter getFilter() {
        FileFilter patternFilter = new FileFilter() {

            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("application" + "\\.xml");
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("application" + "\\.xml.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
            Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("application" + "#..xml");

            @Override
            public boolean accept(final File file) {
                boolean first = p1.matcher(file.getName()).matches();
                boolean second = p2.matcher(file.getName()).matches();
                boolean third = p3.matcher(file.getName()).matches();

                return first | second | third;
            }
        };
        return patternFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. You need to create patterns with `|`(pipeline): [https://regex101.com/r/eF1pH2/1](https://regex101.com/r/eF1pH2/1)

Comment: Try [`application(?:#[^.]*)?\\.xml(?:\\.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?`](https://regex101.com/r/sJ3sT0/1)

Comment: application(\\.xml|#\\d+.xml|\\.xml\\.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not building your pattern dynamically, you may use *optional groups*:

```
application(?:#[^.]*)?\\.xml(?:\\.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ3sT0/1)

*Explanation:*

- `application` - a literal string `application`
- `(?:#[^.]*)?` - one or zero (=optional) `#` followed by zero or more characters other than a period
- `\\.xml` - a literal `.xml`
- `(?:\\.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?` - one or zero (=optional) sequences of a dot followed by 4 digits followed by 2 sequences of a `-` followed by 2 digits

Your updated code in Java will look like:

```
 public static FileFilter getFilter() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("application(?:#[^.]*)?\\.xml(?:\\.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?");
    FileFilter patternFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(final File file) {
           return p.matcher(file.getName()).matches();
        };
        return patternFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst Matcher/Pattern and String#matches yield the same effect, they perform very differently. By using Matcher/Pattern you can parse the pattern once (eg. storing the Pattern as a static). This will have far better performance than String#matches which has to parse the pattern each time

Comment: @LanceJava: Ok, just thought about how to shorten the code, but I see that bottleneck now. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 3 different patterns use 1 pattern combining them with `|` operator.

So instead of:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("application" + "\\.xml");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("application" + "\\.xml.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("application" + "#..xml");
```

use the following

```
String p1 = "application" + "\\.xml";
String p2 = "application" + "\\.xml.\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}";
String p3 = "application" + "#..xml";

Pattern p = "(" + p1 + ")|(" + p2 + ")|(" + p3 + ")";
```

Comment: p1 must be at the last, because it's less ambitious. Or, put `^$` operators

Comment: @Andy yes it is possible also to refactor that regular expression in a smaller one, but probably piping the 3 original regular expressions is more readable for the OP

Comment: It is good if there are just 3 alternatives, but if there are a lot more, this approach might result in a StackOverFlow issue. I suggest using optional groups.

Comment: @stribizhev yes this is a solution tailored on the OP request